# Does this condition make a manifold smooth/analytic?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry

**Question 1**

Specifically, if we have an orientable $n$-dimensional manifold $\mathcal{M}$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and we require that the class of all outward-facing normal vectors $\mathcal{N}_\mathcal{M}$ at all points of $\mathcal{M}$ form a vector space, does this force the manifold to be smooth or analytic? Being closed under vector addition seems like it would make the manifold smooth, and the existence of inverses makes me think that the surface would have to be closed in the $2$-manifold case.

EDIT: I believe this can be phrased also as: if the image of the Gauss map for an $n$-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ has no 'holes' in it, does this impose any particularly nice conditions on the surface? It seems like the Gauss-Bonnet theorem might come into play here?

**Question 2**

If we drop the requirement that inverses exist but maintain all the other structure requirements for a vector field, does this allow for open manifolds like a (finite) plane?

EDIT: I believe that this is equivalent to allowing for a non-symmetric image for the the surface under the Gauss map, but this might not be what I want to say. (is there a 'canonical' Gauss mapping?)

Does this change for non-orientable manifolds?  Any references to appropriate literature would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are outward-facing normal vectors? Is your $M$ inside some euclidean space (may be $\mathbb R^{n+1}$)?

Comment: I don't understand what inverses you are referring to.

Comment: Fixed the question, thanks,
@gary I'm referring to the requirement that all elements of a vector space have an additive inverse under the addition operation in the vector space, in this case addition of normal vectors.  If we require that all normal vectors must have an inverse normal vector in the sense that they sum to the zero vector, then I think the surface has to be closed.

Comment: Alec, what do you mean by an outward-facing normal vector to a manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ not necessarily smoothly?

Comment: Assuming the manifold is orientable, I believe we can develop a notion of the 'inside' and 'outside' of the manifold and each point $p\in\mathcal{M}$ should have two choices for a vector $v_p$ and $v*_p$ such that $v_p$ points 'into' the manifold into the ambient space while $v*_p$ points 'out of' the manifold into the ambient space, no? I just want to choose the class of vectors pointing 'out' of a surface. I'm new to these kinds of topics and drawing intuition from $2$-manifolds,, so I apologize if some part of these assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: Every vector in the plane is an outward normal to the polar graph $r = 1 + \cos\theta$, which has a cusp. It's equally easy to make such an example non-analytic by "smoothly flattening" some portion of the curve. Is that not a counterexample to what you're asking?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I'm asking if the class of vectors $\mathcal{N}_\mathcal{M}$ satisfying the vector space axioms makes $\mathcal{M}$ a smooth or analytic manifold. In the case that $\mathcal{M}$ is closed, I think you've given a nice counterexample.  What if I ask for a non-continuous manifold, or require that it be open?

Comment: Both sides of what you're asking for are poorly formulated for getting a relationship here. But if I'm allowed to change "smoothness" to a more global property, and "forms a vector space" (this is slightly nonsensical; I guess you mean surjective or something) with the more robust "the gauss map has a certain degree" there may be something interesting to you there. Look up "degree of the Gauss map."

Comment: @aes By "forms a vector space", I mean that $$\forall v\big[v\in\mathcal{N}_\mathcal{M}\implies\exists w\exists 0\big(w\in\mathcal{N}_\mathcal{M}\wedge0\in\mathcal{N}_\mathcal{M}\wedge v+0=v\wedge v+w=0\big)\big],$$ and also scalar multiplication is absorbed and the members are closed under addition; I do not know how to be clearer than this. For example, if we consider two disjoint bounded planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which are not parallel, the normal vectors are not closed under addition. If we connect the planes smoothly, we will form a vector space since they will be closed under addition.

Comment: I think we can mod out by scalar multiplication however, since if $v_p$ is normal to $\mathcal{M}$ at $p\in\mathcal{M}$ then so is $\alpha v_p$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+\sim\{0\}$.

Comment: @AlecRhea I'm not thinking of anything particularly interesting about the normal vectors and their multiples forming a vector space. The fact that the "normal vectors point in all possible directions" (i.e. the Gauss map is surjective), or even better (and more stable) the fact that the Gauss map has nonzero degree is what I'd suggest is closer to the intuition you might be having, and does have quite interesting facts related to it. Look up the Gauss map and its relationship to Euler characteristic.

Comment: @aes Thanks for the suggestions, I'll see if I can refine the question.